# turning around using mouse in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Thanks for stack overflow community for helping many ammature coders like me

And now here i got my camera movement like a First person, im able to move forward, backward, sideways and look around(rotate) using arrow keys. And now i want to add the look around using mouse aswell, click and drag to look sideways, up and down.. i tried three.js-pointlocker,firstperson controlls, but none were suitable for my requirement. is there anyway i can get to try mouse look along with my existing keyboard movements ?

I used THREEx.Keyboardstate.js for keyboard movements from stemkoshi

```
var delta = clock.getDelta();
var moveDistance = 50 * delta; // 200 pixels per second
    var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;  

if ( keyboard.pressed("W") || keyboard.pressed("up"))
        camera.translateZ( -moveDistance );
    if ( keyboard.pressed("S")|| keyboard.pressed("down"))
        camera.translateZ(  moveDistance );
    if ( keyboard.pressed("Q") )
        camera.translateX( -moveDistance );
    if ( keyboard.pressed("E") )
        camera.translateX(  moveDistance );

        var rotation_matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().identity();
    if ( keyboard.pressed("A")|| keyboard.pressed("left") )
        camera.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
    if ( keyboard.pressed("D")|| keyboard.pressed("right") )
        camera.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);
    if ( keyboard.pressed("R") )
        camera.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), rotateAngle);
    if ( keyboard.pressed("F") )
        camera.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), -rotateAngle);

    if ( keyboard.pressed("Z") )
    {
        camera.position.set(0,17,0);
        camera.rotation.set(0,0,0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Updated (Even simpler!)

[Working example (on CodePen).](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNNNzJ)

1. a. Create a `mousedown` event listener that records the initial position of the mouse (`event.clientX`, `event.clientY`) as `startX` and `startY`.

   b. In the `mousedown` callback, add a `mousemove` event listener.

   c. Create a `mouseup` event listener that removes the `mousemove` listener.
2. a.  In the `mousemove` callback, record the new mouse position `newX`,`newY`. Update `camera.rotation` by a function of `newX-startX` and `newY-startY`. In the linked example, this looks like:

   ```
   camera.rotation.x += newY-startY;
   camera.rotation.y += newX-startX;
   ```

   b. Update `startX = newX`, and `startY=newY`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Vidor, any working examples of this ? ill give this a try. thank you

Comment: @andyram I've updated my answer with a simpler approach, and included a working example. The relevant portion of code is at the **bottom** of the "JavaScript" section.